# What is the difference opening multiThreading between service and controller?

Tags: java, multithreading, transactions

What is the difference opening multiThreading  between the service and controller? When I open multiThreading in the controller, I don't need to open a hibernate session, and I can get the `currentSession`. But,when I open a thread in the service, I must get the hibernate sessionFactory firstly, then open a new session. And at the end, I must close the session. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

```
@Controller

public class TestController extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private TestDao testDao;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/testMultiInService")
    public Object test() {
        GenericListResponse response = testService.testMulti();
        return response;
    }
}

@Service

public class TestServiceImpl extends TestService {

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private TestDao testDao;

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public GenericListResponse testMulti() {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

        TestCallable1 callable1 = new TestCallable1(this, latch);
        Future<List> future1 = taskExecutor.submit(callable1);
        List list = new ArrayList();

        try {
            latch.await();
            if (null != future1)
                list.addAll(future1.get());
            if (null != future2)
                list.addAll(future2.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class TestCallable1 implements Callable<List> {

    private TestService testService;

    private CountDownLatch latch;

    public TestCallable1(TestService testService, CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.testService = testService;
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public List call() throws Exception {
        List list = null;
        try {
            list = testService.getDimArea();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            this.latch.countDown();
            return list;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Could You please describe what is the problem here? And why are you using countdownlatch with executor thread pool? What is the logic you require to do?

Comment: This is just a piece of code for test.And the question is what is the difference opening multiThreading between service and controller. Opening multiThread in controller, we don't need open hibernate session.We cant get the current session.But in the service ,we must open a new session ,and close it at the end .It is too troublesome.How to solve this problem? Do you have other solutions better?Thank you .

Comment: are you actually doing any hibernate logic in your futures? Transactional annotation is opening a session for you but this session is probably not accessible in your future objects executed by executor thread is this what are you saying? IF you want to have it in the same service you could create a non transactional method and call transactional methods on your futures. If you call a method directly it will not create a transaction as it will bypass the proxy but you can inject the same service with Autowired annotation and will get a proxy to use

Comment: You are right. Now, i find the way to solve this problem.Before, i open the thread in the service,and the method called in callable class is the same service,it is not useful to get a proxy to use.Now, i create another service for the method called in callable with transaction.It work.Thank you for your reminder.

Comment: Besides，could you tell some suggestions about how to learn a new technology.Official document concludes so many point,and how do i proceed from these?Or others effective way to study. Please 
help a person who is eager to improve his skills.

Comment: depends on what do you want to learn. I usually want to learn by example and then do the same myself. Just reading the documentation is not for me :)

Comment: You are right.It is important for combining theory with practice.Where do you find the example usually?

Comment: google and stackoverflow, just need to read instead of blindly copy pasting :)

Comment: So many point in the document. How do you find the important or common to read ,study and practice?